# Float image next to title and align paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to coding and I can't seem to figure this one out... I've included an image that I am trying to replicate just for practice. I can't figure out how to float the image next to the title AND center that title vertically. Then I also need to align the text underneath the title.

This is how I've built the HTML for one of the blocks

```
<article>

<header>
<img src="#" alt="#" rel="#" />
<h1>This is the header</h1>
</header>

<p>
this is a paragraph full of text that needs to be aligned underneath the title.
</p>

<footer>
<a href="#"> Read more, aligned underneath paragraph</a>
</footer>

</article>
```

And then as far as the CSS goes, I can't figure it out. I am trying to float the image to the left, then clear the float in the p and footer and set a left margin to align it under the title. This works, but then I can't figure out how to vertically center the h1 with the img.

I hope this makes sense. Again, I'm new so I expect most of my stuff to be wrong but I am eager to learn so I am asking!

[image]

EDIT: I am not asking anyone to write the code for me. Rather, I want to know if my thinking about the float and margin was right... Everything worked except for the vertical alignment of h1...

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to show us what you've tried rather than asking us to write code for you. If you're new to CSS, do some reading and learn the fundamentals, then give it a go.

Comment: You shouldn't use `<header>` or `<footer>` within the `<article>`. They should be in the same level as the article element.

Comment: `<header>` and `<footer>` within an `<article>` is perfectly semantic. Admittedly they are often misused by there is no reason why they cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to aligning the image and the h1 is to make them`inline-block` and then `vertical-align:middle`. No magic numbers required.

```
article header img,
article header h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LamyG)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a good mood. Here's an example how you can solve this. There are various possibilities. This is just one of them:

**CSS**

```
article {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 0 0 60px;
} 

article:before {
    content: url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/DvbWv/)